# Call function within addEventListener withotu implicitly passing the event object

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to Javascript, and I have this line of code:

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', this.switchMonth.bind(this, true), false);
```

and the `switchMonth` function definition is as follows:

```
switchMonth(next, month, year, dayUTC, dates, datesChosen) {}
```

I want the `true` from the `addEventlistener` function to be the first parameter passed to `switchMonth` (boolean `true` as the first parameter for `switchMmonth`). However, in this case, the event object is being passed as a second argument to `switchMonth`. How do I avoid this and pass only one argument to `switchMonth`, which is the boolean value passed inside the `addEventListener` method?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `.bind`, it would probably be a lot easier to pass to `addEventListener` an anonymous function that invokes `switchMonth` with the one desired parameter (and use an arrow function so that `this` is inherited from the outer block).

Also note that the third parameter to `addEventListener`, `useCapture`:

> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.

So, might as well omit it for brevity's sake, else it's just noise.

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.switchMonth(true);
});
```

If you *had* to use `.bind` and `.bind` alone, no other functions, you would have to `bind` *all* parameters to ensure the `event` that gets passed later is discarded:

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', this.switchMonth.bind(
  this,
  true, // next
  undefined, // month
  undefined, // year
  undefined, // dayUTC
  undefined, // dates
  undefined // datesChosen
));
```

(don't do that)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  :) This clears out things. Go ECMA 6!